# tips and tricks for using vim with ruby/ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, macvim

I'm one of those developers who isn't using TextMate with any of his Ruby/Ruby on Rails work. My particular loyalty in this arena lies with vim. What are your favorite tips/tricks for using vim with Ruby and/or Ruby on Rails to make you as efficient as possible when working?

Comment: Similar question found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269230/thinking-of-moving-from-textmate-to-vim-for-rails-dev-what-do-i-need

Comment: Take your pick: "I'm one of those developers who isn't using TextMate with any of his Ruby/Ruby on Rails work."... and the room grows quiet then a voice from the back yells "HERETIC!" or "I'm one of those developers who isn't using TextMate with any of his Ruby/Ruby on Rails work." and everyone in the room says "Welcome to Textmate Anonymous!". :-) I use both TextMate and Vim. I can do everything I want in Vim, but I want to like Textmate too. I can't quit it. I can't go cold turkey. I'm so... weak.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Most important

Get a copy of [rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) it is awesome on millions of levels. [Read the doc](http://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/blob/master/doc/rails.txt). There are way too many tips, :Rview customer, :RSmodel foo, :Rinvert, gf, :Rextract, :Rake and the list goes on and on. You will probably want [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) as well for easy navigation (which you can access using :Rtree)

#### Second most important

Follow tpope on twitter (the author of fugative, rails.vim, haml.vim, vividchalk theme, cucumber.vim and so on), he seems to be posting new related to Rails vim plugins quite regularly (be it syntax highlighting or git integration).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to checkout my ruby/rails specific [vimfiles](https://github.com/krisleech/vimfiles).

Its a useful starting point and has many useful Ruby/Rails plugins bundled and configured.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that really sucks about Textmate is that it doesn't run on Linux. My vim/gvim config is the same on Mac, Windows and Linux. Same fonts, same themes, same plugins and same customizations.

I mostly use Textmate for snippets and quick evaluations for posting here.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an in depth guide on using Textmate features (especially Rails related features) in VIM. It's very relevant to this question.

http://www.jackkinsella.ie/2011/09/05/textmate-to-vim.html

Answer (score -3):

I don't use vim, instead, I'm like those millions of developers using Textmate. Nevertheless, a colleague does use vim/gvim.

By looking at him work, one of the things I wish I could do in Textmate is the ease of working on multiple files at the same time. Basically, you can easily manipulate multiple windows, which is quite handy.